# How do I use GetManifestResourceStream both with .NET Core and .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm compiling a projet both for net462 and dotnetcore2.0.
I have set the net462;dotnetcore2.0

It seems to work but I need to load an embedded resource like this:

```cs
        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Alcuin.Admin.Api.Beans.TypeTraduction.json"))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

It gives me back a null stream.

Here is my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net462</TargetFrameworks>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Beans\TypeTraduction.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Beans\TypeTraduction.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\Common\Alcuin.Common.Basics\Alcuin.Common.Basics.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\Common\Alcuin.Common.Graph\Alcuin.Common.Graph.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Does someone know how to make it work properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind... I just had to remove this section :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Beans\TypeTraduction.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Problem solved.